# C# Newtonsoft Deserialize JSON with items vs array?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization, json.net

I am struggling on trying to deserialize a JSON string:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "result": {
     "campaigns": {
          "1000" : {
              "campaignId": "1000",
              "campaignTitle": "ABC"
          },
          "2000" : {
               "campaignId": "2000",
               "campaignTitle": "ABCD"
         }
    }
}
```

Since the "campaigns" aren't in an array [], how do I handle grabbing each individual campaign details?

json2csharp.com simply has me put the campaignID's as seperate classes, but that doesn't appear optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a choice - a dictionary or an Array

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

Dictionary<string, Campaign> dict = JObject.Parse(json)["result"]["campaigns"]
                                       .ToObject<Dictionary<string, Campaign>>();

Campaign[]  arr = ((JObject)JObject.Parse(json)["result"]["campaigns"]).Properties()
                        .Select(x => x.Value.ToObject<Campaign>())
                        .ToArray();

public class Campaign
{
    public string campaignId { get; set; }
    public string campaignTitle { get; set; }
}
```